# SSRS Report (.rdl) file render slow in asp.net report viewer but run fast from SSRS Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am showing SSRS report(rdl) file in ASP.net report viewer and want to load/render fast or at least equal time to SSRS Server.

Currently, it is taking more time(10 to 15 sec) as compare to SSRS Server(1 or 2 sec) with all reports (10).

I am working on MVC and loading aspx page in ifram to showing reprot.
i use this code.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607382/Running-a-RDL-RDLC-SQL-Report-in-ASP-NET-without-S?msg=5300845#xx5300845xx

For testing purpose, i made the sample asp.net project for showing report but the time is same.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/SummaryNewTest.rdl");

            ReportDataSource rptDS1 = new ReportDataSource("ReportingDataSource", getResultAsDataTable("select * from Table1"));
            ReportDataSource rptDS2 = new ReportDataSource("ReportingDataSourcePrevDay", getResultAsDataTable("select * from Table2"));

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDS1);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDS2);
        }
    }
```

I made on testing project using ReportViewerForMvc but the time is same for report redering.

I will appropriate, if anyone can give any solution.

Answer (score 2):

My project is MVC and i used aspx page for report viewer as iframe.
I am using expression in reports and framework 4.5 was rendering slow.Without expression report render fast.

So, I created New WebForm project with framework 3.5 and now report is rendering fast.

In web config i added trust tag.

```
<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>
```

i got solution from this link.

http://travis.io/blog/2014/10/27/rdlc-performance-issues-dotnet45/

Answer (score 0):

ReportViewer loads very slow and do not shows report compared to SSRS Report in Report server issue resolved by including httpexecutionRetuestTimeOut included and increased the Request timeout   this resolved the issue. due to request time out it is not showing the report